# "TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()" error when adding django_social to INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: python-social-auth

I am tryging to implement django social auth, and to do that I did `pip install social-auth-app-django`, then I went on to add `social_django` to my `INSTALLED_APPS`. After that when I am running the app, I am getting the following error (I am submitting the entire traceback):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\edgar\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "c:\users\edgar\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Edgar\venvs\internet-lead\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Edgar\venvs\internet-lead\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\Edgar\venvs\internet-lead\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\Edgar\venvs\internet-lead\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\Edgar\venvs\internet-lead\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Edgar\venvs\internet-lead\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Edgar\venvs\internet-lead\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\Edgar\venvs\internet-lead\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "c:\users\edgar\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Edgar\venvs\internet-lead\lib\site-packages\social_django\models.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .storage import DjangoUserMixin, DjangoAssociationMixin, \
  File "C:\Users\Edgar\venvs\internet-lead\lib\site-packages\social_django\storage.py", line 9, in <module>
    from social_core.storage import UserMixin, AssociationMixin, NonceMixin, \
  File "C:\Users\Edgar\venvs\internet-lead\lib\site-packages\social_core\storage.py", line 12, in <module>
    from openid.association import Association as OpenIdAssociation
  File "C:\Users\Edgar\venvs\internet-lead\lib\site-packages\openid\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    if len(version_info) != 3:
TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()
```

If I comment out the 'social_django' from the `INSTALLED_APPS`, everything works fine again.
My python version is 3.5.2, and Django 2.2.12. Any ideas ? I am lost...

Answer (score 5):

I faced this error , I fixed it by uninstalling both `python-openid` and `python3-openid` :

```
pip uninstall python-openid 

pip uninstall python3-openid
```

then re-install `python3-openid` using:

```
 pip install python3-openid
```