# object of type 'map' has no len()

Tags: python, django

I tried to run my docker image for my django project and I have got a error:

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/code/Eventful-main/eventful/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 301, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/social_django/models.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .storage import DjangoUserMixin, DjangoAssociationMixin, \
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/social_django/storage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from social_core.storage import UserMixin, AssociationMixin, NonceMixin, \
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/social_core/storage.py", line 9, in <module>
    from openid.association import Association as OpenIdAssociation
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openid/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    if len(version_info) != 3:
TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()
```

I tried to use different version of python but always same issue back to me!

Here my docker file

```
FROM python:3

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY . /code/
RUN pip install -r requairements.txt


EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["gunicorn", "--chdir", "Eventful-main", "--bind", ":8000", "eventful.wsgi:application"]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()" error when adding django\_social to INSTALLED\_APPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62091286/typeerror-object-of-type-map-has-no-len-error-when-adding-django-social-t)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the answer from [Object of type 'map' has no len() in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36982858/object-of-type-map-has-no-len-in-python-3)

"In Python 3, map returns a map object not a list.
You can convert it into a list then get the length from there:

```
>>> print(len(list(L)))
10
```

"

In your case:

```
if len(list(version_info)) != 3:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(len(map.keys()))
```

You can use the length of the key in the map to calculate the length of the map